# Theme.Translucent fails on ICS

Tags: android, themes, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using:
`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

in combination with: 
`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);`

to get a nice transparent background blur effect, emulates a dialog style.

This works great on 2.3 and down, but it is a solid color(read not transparent) on devices running ICS / 3.0 and up. I know they introduced a holo theme and there does not seem to be a specific Theme.Holo.Translucent theme. Any ideas on how to get a translucent background on both ICS and older, I'm not opposed to using separate themes defined in values-v11.

Comment: Does not look like this will solve your issue but in case you missed it: [Holo everywhere](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)

Comment: Could you specify what devices are running on? Does Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar work for you in a newly created, minimal Android project? Does android:hardwareAccelerated true/false make a difference? Does various combinations of attributes in the <uses-sdk ... /> tag make a difference (i.e. different compatibility modes)?

Comment: Just made a new project with minimal manifest (auto generated) and added the theme. Works on my 2.3 devices but not on the Galaxy Nexus. android:hardwareAccelerated does not seem to impact it or uses-sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

or extend Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar and add

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using updated ActionbarSherlock themes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems they deprecated blurring, at least with [FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND):

> public static final int `FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND`
>
> This constant is deprecated. Blurring is no longer supported.

Comment: Good find, but even if I remove that I still don't get the transparency from the theme. So while this is a good tip, it does not actually solve my issue :(